# Get last record of each group in entityframework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to retrieve last inserted record of each **MobileNo** in entity-framework.

Here is my table data.

```
ID      RegNo       MobileNo    CreatedDate
26727   190077348   9696562673  13-02-2017 06:31
26729   123782783   9696562673  13-02-2017 06:35
45779   530087328   5878525875  07-02-2017 07:23
99902   120058572   7379130560  08-02-2017 12:39
64477   180073650   7417516480  10-02-2017 13:47
81839   240087264   7754990580  11-02-2017 10:47
```

and want output like

```
ID      RegNo       MobileNo    CreatedDate 
26729   123782783   9696562673  13-02-2017 06:35
45779   530087328   5878525875  07-02-2017 07:23 
99902   120058572   7379130560  08-02-2017 12:39
64477   180073650   7417516480  10-02-2017 13:47
81839   240087264   7754990580  11-02-2017 10:47
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming the name of your table is `Items`:

```
var result = dbContext.Items.GroupBy(x => x.MobileNo)
                      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedDate).First());
```

Running sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ud2pB

Comment: the solution is not working with EF Core, can you add some sample code for EF Core regarding this.  Thanks

Comment: if its the same error i am having, it is because it does not translate linq into sql.

Comment: @sebu did you find solution for ef core?

Comment: @cikatomo you can check this tutorial: https://medium.com/@pawel.gerr/entity-framework-core-row-number-support-54ac3392f69d

ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION are not implemented in DbFunctions. docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-6.0

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MobileNo ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
   FROM yourtablename
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```