# How to get all unique records with the maximum value in column using LINQ

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
Learner     | AssesmentId | Attempt 
------------------------------------
Parker      |     1       |    1    
Parker      |     1       |    2    
Stark       |     1       |    1    
Rogers      |     1       |    1    
Rogers      |     1       |    2    
Parker      |     1       |    3
```

Given this data, how do I get all the unique Student name with the highest Attempt?
I'm attempting to get this result:

```
Learner     | AssesmentId | Attempt 
------------------------------------
Parker      |     1       |    3    
Stark       |     1       |    1    
Rogers      |     1       |    2
```

How can I do this in a single query in LINQ?

```
from la in _context.LearnerAssessments
where la.AssessmentId == assessmentId
  && learnerIds.Contains(la.LearnerId)
  && la.Attempt == {highest attempt}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get last record of each group in entityframework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274806/get-last-record-of-each-group-in-entityframework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = from list in _context.LearnerAssessments
           group list by new
    {
        list.Learner,
        list.AssesmentId
    }
    into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.Learner,
        g.Key.AssesmentId,
        Max= g.Max(x=>x.Attempt)
    };
```

or using fluent API :

```
var data = _context.LearnerAssessments.GroupBy(l => new { l.Learner, l.AssesmentId }, (keys, item) => new
{
    Key = keys,
    MaxAttemp = item.Max(x => x.Attempt)
}).Select(x => new LearnerAssessment
{
    Learner = x.Key.Learner,
    Attempt = x.MaxAttemp,
    AssesmentId = x.Key.AssesmentId

});
```